# Access the visible template reference inside a template element?

Tags: angular, angular2-nativescript

How do I select element that's currently visible

My attempt was like this:

app.component.html

```
 <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
      <StackLayout width="100%" *ngFor="let item of images$">
          <Image #image [src]="item.url" stretch="aspectFill" colSpan="3" row="0"></Image>
      </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

app.component.ts

```
   @ViewChildren('image') image: QueryList<Image>;
   ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     this.image.changes.subscribe((changes) => {
       alert("current:" + this.image.toArray()[0]);
       alert("current:" + this.image.toArray()[0].src);
      }
     );
   }
```

It alerts only once.

Basically the goal is to trigger API's exposed by Image when scrolled to position of an item in view.

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/VJHqrkRTBsbPtpx5mpUN?p=info

Comment: what is ui-image? the [plunker doesn't work](https://plnkr.co/edit/s40RpCmWI6lnPGsDpHgO?p=preview)

Comment: it's nativescript library. on my local it works that way as its a nativescript project i guess. maybe there i need to give `tns-core-modules/ui/image`

Comment: can you answer considering it to be any angular element, wanted to keep nativescript part separate, that's why i didn't dive into API's of exposed lib etc as I would put that as a separate question if i am still stuck after being able to access the angular element as desired.

Comment: @ishandutta2007 your plunker is in complete

Comment: Ignore plunker and let me know if you have any idea on the problem I mentioned above. My plunker is definitely not in the right direction, i don't see point in trying to debug that code.

Comment: @Maximus any ideas ?

Comment: haven't had a chance to look yet, will take a look later